# searching base64 decoded binary data for text in Python

Tags: python, base64

I have some data in a database that is base64 encoded

I am decoding it easily enough with

```
b64 = base64.b64decode(row[2])
```

however I now need to search the decoded data for various text strings and get the offsets of said strings. The decoded data is binary i.e. it contains lots of non-printables, NULLs etc.

I have tried

```
ofs = b64.find('content')
```

but get an error `TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API`

which shows I am clearly barking up the wrong tree

I am new to Python but for various reasons want to try and get a solution using it - any ideas please?

Comment: What does it matter that the data was previously base64 encoded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes) object instead of a [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#str)

```
ofs = b64.find(b'content')
```

or a little less hard-coded way

```
search = 'content'
ofs = b64.find(bytes(search))
```

As `ofs` in encoded as [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes), you should look for a corresponding object inside it ;).

---

From the Docs, `bytes` when used as function returns a new `bytes` object:

> *bytes([source[, encoding[, errors]]])*
>
> Return a new “bytes” object, which is an immutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256. bytes is an immutable version of bytearray – it has the same non-mutating methods and the same indexing and slicing behavior.